# Change background-position without animation

Tags: html, css

I've got this code working for changing background conteniosly in CSS and HTML:

```
animation: animated 10s linear infinite;

@keyframes animated {
    0% { background-position: 0px bottom; }
    25% { background-position: -200px bottom; }
    50% { background-position: -400px bottom; }
    75% { background-position: -600px bottom; }
}
```

Currently the background moves in an animation, but I would like to have the background switch position in one go - so it seems the image changes instead of moving.

Is that possible with only CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is, instead of

```
25% { background-position: -200px bottom; }
50% { background-position: -400px bottom; }
```

You do it like:

```
25.01%, 50% { background-position: -200px bottom; }
50.01%, 75% { background-position: -400px bottom; }
```

Thus you will *almost* eliminate the time needed for transition from one keyframe to another.

**Demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cw7ru9je/)**

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }
#bg{ width:100%; height:100vh;
  background: url('//www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Fall-Nature-Background-Pictures.jpg') no-repeat;
  animation: slideshow 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes slideshow {
  0%, 25% { background-position: 0px bottom; }
  25.01%, 50% { background-position: -200px bottom; }
  50.01%, 75% { background-position: -400px bottom; }
  75.01%, 100% { background-position: -600px bottom; }
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Elegant :) At least in my opinion.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) enjoy coding!

Comment: Actually, I just read the other answers and @Gerard provided a better answer by making use of CSS [**`steps()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#The_steps()_class_of_timing-functions) which I totally forgot about, that's the best answer but with a little tweak..  `animation: animated 10s steps(4) infinite;` **https://jsfiddle.net/cw7ru9je/3/**

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
animation: animated 10s steps(4) linear infinite;
@keyframes animated {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }
  to {
    background-position: 600px 0px; }
}
```

Comment: Yes definitely better, upvote, here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cw7ru9je/3/) for this answer, however, it should be `animation: animated 10s steps(4) infinite;` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `linear` in your CSS

```
animation: animated 10s infinite;

@keyframes animated {
    0% { background-position: 0px bottom; }
    25% { background-position: -200px bottom; }
    50% { background-position: -400px bottom; }
    75% { background-position: -600px bottom; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that simply change the background-position once, without it changing endlessly between the 4 background-positions?

Comment: The "animation: animated 10s infinite;" gives a sort of ease-in animation :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some JS with `setTimeout` of `10000ms` to switch background-position

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var koef = 1;

  setInterval(function () {
    $('#image').css({'background-position-x': 600 * -koef});
    koef = !koef;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/200/) no-repeat 0 bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't that simply change the background-position once, without it changing endlessly between the 4 background-positions?

Comment: @MichaelNielsen And how do you imagine changing instantly background position infinite times? I image it as switching to one way and that is it.

Comment: A bit like the code example I gave, where it endlessly moves position - it's just that currently it's moving the background bit by bit, instead of "jumping" directly to position -200, then -400, -600 and back to 0 in 10 seconds.